# unable to Start Profile Synchronization in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, target-audience

i am unable to Start Profile Synchronization in sharepoint 2010 from central admin
due to which the `Compile Audiences` does not work

an error message pop up when i click on `Start Profile Synchronization` [image: Error Message]

" " can not navigate to the requested page while user profile synchronization is running please wait for current synchronization run to finish. ""

please help regarding this problem

thanks in advance

`this problem occurred in windows 7` how ever it worked fine with Server2008

Answer (score 0):

The way i understand it, when you install sharepoint 2010 on your desktop (Windows 7), certain components are very picky about how they are installed (user profiles sync), and some just wont install (FAST search).

This is pretty much the reason i stuck with creating vm's for development.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to resolve this is, open the Forefront Identity Manager 2010 and check for the actual failure. Most of the cases you get problems because of the user trying to connect to AD do not have replication directory changes access.
Take a look at this post:
http://sharepoint-2010-world.blogspot.com/2011/02/cannot-navigate-to-requested-page-while.html